# What is iterator.element in swift?

Tags: swift, iterator

I am just following iterator pattern, could you tell me what is `S.Iterator.Element` in below code & what is mean of  `Int where Turn == S.Iterator.Element` ?

```
 func computeScoreIncrement<S : Sequence>(_ pastTurnsReversed: S) -> Int where Turn == S.Iterator.Element {
    var scoreIncrement: Int?
    for turn in pastTurnsReversed {
      if scoreIncrement == nil {
        scoreIncrement = turn.matched! ? 1 : -1
        break
      }
    }
//Turn is class name & nextScorer is protocol instance.
    return (scoreIncrement ?? 0) + (nextScorer?.computeScoreIncrement(pastTurnsReversed) ?? 0)
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Iterator.Element` is the easiest to understand here. The generic parameter `S` must be a type that conforms to `Sequence`, as you've specified here:

```
func computeScoreIncrement<S : Sequence>(_ pastTurnsReversed: S) -> Int
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Therefore, `S.Iterator.Element` refers to the type of sequence that `S` is. If, say, `S` is inferred to be `[Int]`, then `S.Iterator.Element` is `Int` - `[Int]` is a sequence of `Int`.

Now onto the `where Turn == S.Iterator.Element` part.

As mentioned above, `S` must be a type that conforms to `Sequence`, but that's not all of the constraints! `S.Iterator.Element` must also be the *same* type as `Turn`. You didn't show how `Turn` is defined. It may be a generic parameter of the enclosing class, a class, struct or enum.

Thus, I can pass a `[Turn]` to this method, to instances of some other type that is a sequence of `Turn`s.

Comment: Thanks ! Great explanation.